# What is the best k in kmeans clustering

Tags: machine-learning, clustering, data-visualization, k-means

I did clustering on a dataset of real-world patients and since the best way to choose the amount of clusters in KMeans clustering is Elbow method and the Silhouette method, I conducted those two and the results are plotted in the graphs below.

The Elbow Method plotted in the graph below
[image]

The Silhouette Method is plotted in the graph below
[image]

From multiple blogs, I saw if it is unable to identify the correct amount of clusters correctly using the elbow method, then conduct the Silhouette method. But even by conducting both I find it hard to identify the correct k. A snap of the dataset I have conducted clustering is also added below,
[image]

Any idea on which is the correct k? Please provide clarification for the answer also since I am afraid of whether I understand them correctly or not.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The right k for kmeans depends on your goal. What further analysis do you want to carry out with these clusters?

Comment: Before moving on to the question about the number of clusters, did you remember to normalize/standardize the features?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/23472/how-to-decide-on-the-correct-number-of-clusters

Answer (score 0):

The Elbow Method can sometimes provide a very clear answer, but often it's hard to discriminate the elbow or bend that reveals the best clusters. In the absence of a clear elbow, one can then turn to the Silhouette Method, which involves examining the average Silhouette Coefficient (SC) and finding the number of clusters k that maximize this value (with the understanding that if two values of k are relatively close, there's often a benefit to choosing the simpler model.)

In the case of your diagram for the average SC, it's important to note that the [coefficient is only defined for values of 2 and above](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.silhouette_score.html). Therefore, the highest average SC was present when two clusters were generated, so k = 2 would be your choice using this approach. Having said this, the average SC is still pretty low when k = 2 (just under 0.1), and this led to my question in the comments as to whether you standardized the features before performing K-means clustering.